# Angular JS seo for beginners

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, phantomjs, prerender

I've just built an angular js web application and I'm trying to make it crawlable so that it can be indexed correctly by google. Also so I can apply for adsense approval. I've looked into solutions but I'm finding them quite confusing. Most discuss using phantom js or an equivalent to take dynamic snapshots of the content and then feeding these to the bots, but I really can't get my head around it. My site is at www.covervidz.com. Can anyone help?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into a service called Prerender.io - They solve this issue. Failing that you can try serving up static html files which update periodically.

Comment: Hey thanks, I had checked out pre-render but got confused but on closer inspection their methods seem pretty straight forward.